# New computer won't boot at all

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply

I have just bought a brand new computer in parts. I assembled it and tried it, but it is not booting.

Parts:

- Intel Core i5-4590
- 2 x 4GB of Kingston HyperX Genesis RAM
- Gigabyte Z87-DS3H
- Asus nVidia GeForce GTX 770 (disconnected, no effect)
- Corsair CX750
- WD Green 2TB (disconnected, no effect)
- Antec Three Hundred Two

First when we tried to boot the fans and drives turned on for maybe 2 seconds, then everything turned off for a couple of seconds, and then the cycle restarted.

We tried using the motherboard's CMOS reset switch; when the switch is disconnected everything seems to turn on, but nothing actually happens (same fans & drives on effect). But now, the power switch just turns everything on for half a second and then off again.

The case does not have a speaker, so I am not able to hear any beep codes.

What should I try to fix this?

Comment: Try replacement parts. Welcome to computer building, you need spares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your motherboard may require BIOS update to support this CPU.

i5-4590 is a 4th generation Core CPU (first digit in the 4-digit model name, 3-digit models are 1st gen). 4th gen support was added in F2 BIOS (source: [BIOS download page](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4761#bios)). If your motherboard doesn't have F2 or F3 BIOS, then it won't start properly with 4th gen CPUs.

If that's the case then you have to get a 3rd gen or older CPU for this socket, install it and flash latest BIOS. Unfortunately there's no way to determine if it's the old BIOS that causes this issue - checking BIOS version is possible only after booting.

Comment: Tried assembling a friend's computer, an identical mobo worked first try with an i5-4570.

Comment: Well, your answer was actually the solution. I personally find it weird that a 4590 doesn't work while a 4570 does.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should re-check all the cable and hardware connections in the PC and also I would suggest to try a different PSU. I encountered a similar problem when my graphics card was not mounted properly on the PCI express slot. Also as mentioned maybe a bios update would do the trick..